# Filtering vertices in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, graph-traversal

Say I have a directed acyclic graph with N vertices and a subset of the vertices at size M.

The M vertices are all marked as visited, how can I find all the vertices that all of their predecessors in the graph are visited

for example: if there are 4 vertices a,b,c,u and 3 edges (a,u) (b,u) (c,u) and a,b,c are marked as visited I need to output u .

I was thinking of going through all the vertices and for each vertex check all of his predecessors but I think that this isn't much efficient..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete those M vertices from the original graph. This can be done by just removing the outgoing edges from the 'visited' nodes.

The nodes that are not in M and that are not reachable from any other vertex have all their predecessors visited (in M).

If the graph is of the form of an adjacency matrix then this can be done by just scanning each column and checking whether there is any non-zero entry in it.